# Detect a swipe gesture on webview

Tags: android, webview, swipe-gesture, gesturedetector

I would like to have a WebView how can detect swipe gesture for close my Activty when I swipe my finger left to right.

**Gesture detector :**

```
private class CustomeGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {      
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        if(e1 == null || e2 == null) return false;
        if(e1.getPointerCount() > 1 || e2.getPointerCount() > 1) return false;
        else {
            try { // right to left swipe .. go to next page
                if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > 100 && Math.abs(velocityX) > 800) {
                    //do your stuff
                    return true;
                } //left to right swipe .. go to prev page
                else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > 100 && Math.abs(velocityX) > 800) {
                    //do your stuff
                    return true;
                } //bottom to top, go to next document
                else if(e1.getY() - e2.getY() > 100 && Math.abs(velocityY) > 800 
                        && webView.getScrollY() >= webView.getScale() * (webView.getContentHeight() - webView.getHeight())) {
                    //do your stuff
                    return true;
                } //top to bottom, go to prev document
                else if (e2.getY() - e1.getY() > 100 && Math.abs(velocityY) > 800 ) {
                    //do your stuff
                    return true;
                } 
            } catch (Exception e) { // nothing
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Custom WebView**

```
public final class CustomWebView extends WebView {

private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

/**
 * @param context
 * @param attrs
 * @param defStyle
 */
public CustomWebView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

/**
 * @param context
 * @param attrs
 * @param defStyle
 */
public CustomWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

/**
 * @param context
 * @param attrs
 * @param defStyle
 */
public CustomWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

/* 
 * @see android.webkit.WebView#onScrollChanged(int, int, int, int)
 */
@Override
protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
    super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
}

/* 
 * @see android.webkit.WebView#onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)
 */
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev) || super.onTouchEvent(ev);
}

public void setGestureDetector(GestureDetector gestureDetector) {
    this.gestureDetector = gestureDetector;
}
}
```

**In my onCreate Activity but setGestureDetector is undefined for the Object type :**

```
webView.setGestureDetector(new GestureDetector(new CustomeGestureDetector()));
```

How can I put instead of setGestureDetector(new GestureDetector(new CustomeGestureDetector())); for initialize my webview ?

Answer (score 0):

try to use the ontouch of webview

```
   webView.setOnTouchListener(this);
   gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new CustomeGestureDetector());
```

and override this touch event

```
 @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)){
            Log.v(TAG,"screen touched");
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where I put the onTouchEvent, in my Activity or in my custom WebView ?

Comment: setOnTouchListener doesn't exist for a webview